# Only allow a user with certain roles to access files in a folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I am trying to secure files in a folder so that only certain users with certain roles can access the files.

I am using ASP.Net MVC 4.5, Identity Framework and know your used to be able to write a HTTPHandler that would sit in the request pipeline and give you a hook to handle the request.

This doesn't seem to work in ASP.Net MVC for some reason.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace Test.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles processing requests for protected web application files, such as reports/*.pdf
    /// The reports are checked by the user role to determine access.
    /// </summary>
    public class FileProtectionHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
            {
                case "GET":
                {
                    // Is the user logged-in?
                    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                        return;
                    }

                    string requestedFile = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath);

                    // Verify the user has access to the User role.
                    if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin") || context.User.IsInRole("Role1") || context.User.IsInRole("Rol2") || context.User.IsInRole("Role3") || context.User.IsInRole("Role4"))
                    {
                        SendContentTypeAndFile(context, requestedFile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Deny access, redirect to error page or back to login page.
                        context.Response.Redirect("~/login");
                        //FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private HttpContext SendContentTypeAndFile(HttpContext context, String strFile)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(strFile);
            context.Response.TransmitFile(strFile);
            context.Response.End();

            return context;
        }

        private string GetContentType(string filename)
        {
            // used to set the encoding for the reponse stream
            string res = null;
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filename);

            if (fileinfo.Exists)
            {
                switch (fileinfo.Extension.Remove(0, 1).ToLower())
                {
                    case "pdf":
                    {
                        res = "application/pdf";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return res;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your test user is indeed in one of those roles. What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: It wasn't even hitting the code, apparently you need to set up routing to allow static files to pass through the request pipeline.